# Can I delete parts of bootstrap.min.css that I'm not using?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, minify, bundling-and-minification

I have a small React app that I'm minifying with Webpack, and I noticed that ~80% of my minified index.js file is just Bootstrap css that I'm not using, plus Webpack warns me that my entry file is too big (~900kb vs ~250kb recommended). I found a few answers here from a long time ago that said to remove parts of `bootstrap.min.css` file that I don't need, and I'm wondering if that's still the recommended solution for a React app using `react-bootstrap`?

This is my production webpack config:

```json
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require('favicons-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: '/src/index.tsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'prod'),
    },
    mode: 'production',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-toastify/dist'),
                    path.resolve(
                        __dirname,
                        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
                    ),
                    path.resolve(
                        __dirname,
                        'node_modules/react-grid-layout/css/styles.css'
                    ),
                    path.resolve(
                        __dirname,
                        'node_modules/react-resizable/css/styles.css'
                    ),
                ],
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
        }),
        new FaviconsWebpackPlugin('./src/logo.png'),
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
    },
}
```

And at the top of my App.tsx file I have

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I was able to (I think) accomplish what I was asking. I first tried to follow the instructions here:
https://medium.com/dwarves-foundation/remove-unused-css-styles-from-bootstrap-using-purgecss-88395a2c5772

So running `purgecss --css [path to bootstrap css] ---content src/index.html --output public` did create very minified CSS files, but either I did something wrong or purgecss removed too much, because the bootstrap styles didn't seem to be applied to anything.

Instead, I installed MiniCssExtractPlugin, and pointed webpack to the full `bootstrap.min.css` file. Running webpack with the below (updated) webpack.prod.js config file reduced the entry file size from ~900kb to ~360kb, which is still above the recommended limit but is about 1/3 the size of the entry before these changes.

Edit: and it also seems good that now the css styles are in their own actual main.css file, rather than for some reason being inside main.js, which is how it was before adding MiniCssExtractPlugin.

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require('favicons-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: '/src/index.tsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'prod'),
    },
    mode: 'production',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
                ],
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename: "[name].css", chunkFilename: "[id].css"}),
        new FaviconsWebpackPlugin('./src/logo.png'),
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
    },
}
```